# how to clear the specific lines from file based on some string in file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file as below -

```
Password:   
Msg 2401, Level 11, State 2:  
Server 'test':  
Character set conversion is not available between client character set 'utf8' and server character set 'iso_1'.  
No conversions will be done.  
|Extraction_Date|Agent_Cde_1|Agent_Cde_2|Agent_Cde_3|Agent_Cde_4|Agent_Name  
|20140902       |0010       |       NULL|       NULL|       NULL|NULL
```

I want to delete all the lines which are present before column names. The number of lines present before column names can vary every time. Is there any way wherein we can check for 'Extraction_date' string and delete all the lines present above it using unix commands ?

Comment: Do you realize you really want "every line containing a column (|)"?

Comment: `sed -n '/Extraction_Date/,$p' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will print all line starting from `Extraction` date:

```
awk '/^\|Extraction_Date/ {f=1} f' file
|Extraction_Date|Agent_Cde_1|Agent_Cde_2|Agent_Cde_3|Agent_Cde_4|Agent_Name  
|20140902       |0010       |       NULL|       NULL|       NULL|NULL
```

Or this may be ok:

```
awk '/^\|/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the grep command

```
grep -F '|'
```

Answer (score 1):

using **sed** address range:

```
sed -n '/^|Extraction_Date/,$p' file
```